# How to connect Azure media services to android application?

Tags: android, azure, android-mediaplayer, azure-media-services

I have connected a raspberry pi USB camera to Azure media services(AMS) for live streaming, now I want to integrate AMS to my android app? How am I supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to know how to consume the video on android app, which comes from the USB camera of Raspberry PI and stream up to AMS.

Accroding to the offical tutorial, I think there are two ways to playback the video on AMS via Android.

1. Using the existing players on Android, please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-playback-content-with-existing-players).
2. Developing & integrating a video player for your android app, please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-develop-video-players).

Comment: Ok, Thank you Peter Pan. I will try it.